# SQL SERVER: I would like to transfer my data to another column of the same table before droping the first one

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am having problems with some of my SQL scripts on SQL SERVER, indeed I am trying to transfer data from a column A to a column B of the same table and then drop the column B,

However my problem is that I have to check for the existence of A beforehand because the code is meant to be executed on a server where I don't have access (I work as a third party developper on a professionnal app)

Here is my code:

```
-- Export the data from the column name
-- Drop the column name

USE p_mynacellelocation_db_ChecklistWPF
GO


IF COL_LENGTH('model_trolley_part','name') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
UPDATE model_trolley_part
SET name_en=[name];

ALTER TABLE model_trolley_part
DROP COLUMN [name];
END
```

In the case of the column name being non existent I would like not to do anything

However on execution of the code in a database where the column name is non existent SQL Server returns me:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1,  Line 12 Invalid column name 'name'.

Comment: Is `name` a valid column in your table? Why do you need to copy a column into another column and then drop the original? That isn't really accomplishing anything. What is your overall requirement and goal?

Comment: Why not simply rename the column? Copying the data to a new column and then dropping the original is way over complicating this. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-rename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: If you just need to copy data from column A to column B, then you don't need to worry about whether data exists or not. Just `UPDATE model_trolley_part SET name_en=[name]` with no other qualification, and if it doesn't exist, then there won't be anything to set in that row.

Comment: Sorry, misread your original question. You want to check if the original column exists before you copy, not whether it has data in it. Again, why copy it just to drop it? This sounds a little like it may be an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of jumping through all these hoops simply rename your original column.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-rename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

```
exec sp_rename 'model_trolley_part.name', 'name_en', 'COLUMN'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use dynamic SQL for this.   The reason is that the parser will try to validate your code, even the code that won't be executed because its `IF` condition wouldn't be met.

The parser is smart enough to see there is no table named `name`, but it's not smart enough to realize that the code shouldn't get executed because of the `IF`, so it raises a parsing error.

Using dynamic SQL in the `BEGIN..END` block after the `IF` hides this from the parser so it will execute.

Comment: I have no clue on how to work with Dynamic SQL but I will do some research

Comment: Thanks a million for your quick answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT *
          FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
          WHERE  TABLE_NAME = 'myTableName'
                 AND COLUMN_NAME = 'ColumnA') 
BEGIN

// your update and drop code goes here

END
```

you might want to check your account privileges if you are modifying table structure etc..